# TextFormFields in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, text

Can i use flutter's text form field to create a page similar to Instagram's 'edit profile'? When i click edit profile, my name and username is already displayed in the box and i can change it if i want to, and then save it. Currently, i am trying to use text form field to do this but i am unable to do it such that when i enter the page, my respective data is already in the box. Hence, i am unable to see my information (what i previously keyed in).

Right now, i have used a few TextEditingControllers and controllers to store my data in firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when creating a text field, you need to pass in a **TextEditingController.** TextEditingController's have a constructor for **text** that you can use to set a starting value.
Example Code:

```
TextEditingController nameController = new TextEditingController(text: username); //the controller
TextFormField( //the text field with your username already passed in
      controller: nameController,
)
```